# Class not being recognised

Tags: c++, class

This is the code i have:

```
template <class a, class b>
class LinkedListIter{

    public:
        LinkedListIter(b* iterable){

            this->iterable = iterable;
            this->head = this->iterable->head;
            this->curr = this->iterable->curr;
            this->iter_pos = 0;

        };
        void operator++(int dummy){

            this->iter_pos++;

        };
        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, LinkedListIter const& lli);

    private:
        a* head;
        a* curr;
        b* iterable;
        int iter_pos; //The current position if the iterator

    };

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, LinkedListIter const& lli){ 
    return o << lli.get(lli.iter_pos); 
}
```

I get an error on the line where i declared `std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, LinkedListIter const& lli)` saying that LinkedListIter doesn't name a type. Why is it so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LinkedListIter` is a class template, not a class.  So your operator needs to be a template also.

```
template<typename a, typename b>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, LinkedListIter<a,b> const & lli){
...
```

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi: If you have another question, it would be better to make a separate post.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

template <class a, class b>
class LinkedListIter;

template <class a, class b>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, LinkedListIter<a, b> const& lli);

template <class a, class b>
class LinkedListIter{
    public:
        LinkedListIter(b* iterable) {

            this->iterable = iterable;
            this->head = this->iterable->head;
            this->curr = this->iterable->curr;
            this->iter_pos = 0;

        };
        void operator++(int dummy) {

            this->iter_pos++;

        };
        friend std::ostream& operator<< <a, b> (std::ostream& o, LinkedListIter const& lli);

    private:
        a* head;
        a* curr;
        b* iterable;
        int iter_pos; //The current position if the iterator

};

template <class a, class b>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, LinkedListIter<a, b> const& lli) { 
    return o << lli.get(lli.iter_pos); 
}
```

this code can compile well, wish help.